# Convert numbers between 0 and infinity to numbers between 0.0 and 1.0

Tags: real-numbers, number-line

Can we arrange all numbers `x;` such that `x` lies between `0` and `Infinity`, between `0` and `1`? The scale does not have to be linear, but for any `a` and `b` in `x`, where `a <= b`, then `a'` and `b'`, the equivalent numbers on the new scale must also be such that: `a' <= b'`.

I am really curious about this as I need it for a ratings system.

Thanks!

Comment: "The scale does not have to be linear" how fortunate!

Comment: @mdup, lol!, yeah... I have very mild requirements.... until something changes lol

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\exp$ is a great tool, but there's also 
$$
x \mapsto \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}
$$
which may be slightly easier to work with in some situations.

As @Servaes points out, you can also use
$$
x \mapsto \frac{x}{1+x}
$$
because you're working on the nonnegative reals rather than all reals.

And a personal favorite of mine is 
$$
x \mapsto \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(x).
$$

Comment: And in fact there is no need for the squares as the function is needed on the nonnegative reals only.

Comment: Good point. Edited.

Comment: A slight addition could be "y=1 / (1 + M/ x)". This maps x=M to y=0.5

Answer (score 9):

There are many options, one example is the function $f(x)=e^{-x}$. It maps the domain $(0,\infty)$ onto the range $(0,1)$, though it reverses the ordering. That is, if $x<y$ then $f(x)>f(y)$. This is of course easily fixed by taking 
$$g(x)=1-f(x)=1-e^{-x},$$
instead.

Comment: $6$ seconds before me!

Comment: Are you sure this satisfies the second requirement?

Comment: Given that if $a\leq b$ then $a'\leq b'$ I think $1-e^{-x}$ should be what OP is looking for.

Comment: a=0, b=1 is a counterexample though, right?

Comment: @Infiaria I thought the same, see my edit.

Comment: Wow, I . am impressed with the dexterity and eagerness here. Thanks so much for helping out! I have to accept the other answer by @John Hughes, though. Because I need the answers not to converge too quickly towards 1. 
Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 2):

The expression you are looking for is a one-to-one mapping from positive reals into $[0,1]$. Consider the exponential mapping $f_k(x) = exp(- (x^k))$. Other people suggested $f_2$. There exist other mappings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $$g(x) = 1-2^{-x},$$ and any numbers between 0 and Infinity will be mapped to between 0 and 1.

I'm not very well versed in what's covered in the rest of the answers, so this may have already been stated a different way, but this is here if it hasn't.